# ApplicationInsights logging with ILogger is duplicating traces - logs appearing twice

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, ilogger, appinsights

I have a .NET Core API and I am logging to Azure AppInsights using `ILogger` DI.
This is using the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` nuget package and documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core

In my Program.cs I register it like so:

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

In my API I inject ILogger like so:

```
public FileService(ILogger<FileService> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

and use it like so:

```
_logger.LogInformation($"Starting upload");
```

This works fine and my logs are appearing as traces in AppInsights, but every time I log, two identical traces appear:

[image]

Note that for each duplicate, the `traceId` is identical. Also, breakpoints on my log statements show that they are only being hit once.

Anybody else experiencing this?

--

UPDATE: I have tried disabling various options but this hasn't stopped the duplication.

```
ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions aiOptions = new();
aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
aiOptions.EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = false;
aiOptions.EnableDebugLogger = false;
aiOptions.EnableDiagnosticsTelemetryModule = false;
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Got no problem with using this package  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights`
program.cs

```
builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights(
        configureTelemetryConfiguration: (config) =>
            config.ConnectionString = "InstrumentationKey=xxxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://xxx.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://eastus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/",
            configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: (options) => { }
    );
builder.Logging.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("provider1", LogLevel.Trace);
```

controller

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ValuesController> _logger;

        public ValuesController(ILogger<ValuesController> logger)
        {
            this._logger = logger;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public void test()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("A info ");
            _logger.LogWarning("A warn ");
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that approach too now. Still duplicating. I think maybe it is something environmental in the way our Azure is set up, and not code-related.